# Print special characters like "à" from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character

I have a database, utf8_general_ci, and I have manually inserted the values into. Between those values, I have also special characters like `à`, `è` and so on. Now what I'm trying to do, is to print those values through PHP. My page has already `<meta charset="utf-8">` , also `$mysqli->real_escape_string` but I still get a ? instead of that characters. Is not a font problem, if I manually `echo "à";` it works, but the data from DB doesn't.

Comment: `real_escape_string` is not for outputting. Did you set the character set of the `mysqli` connection?

Comment: you mean mysqli_query("set names 'utf8'");  than yes

Comment: `mysqli_query("set names 'utf8'")` would do nothing, you need the link there. Please add code to the question.

Comment: solved it with $con->set_charset('utf8');

Comment: If you were using the `real_escape_string` to prevent XSS injections you should look at `htmlspecialchars`. That is for outputting to a browser.